# Can a VPN bypass LAN access restrictions that are based on MAC address

Tags: router, vpn, mac-address

My router can apply MAC-address based restrictions, e.g. to limit access hours for a specific device on the network. (Not to be confused with IP address restrictions to block facebook, youtube etc..) This seems to be a common feature in routers found in DSL modems.

If a rogue user on my LAN uses a VPN app to access the internet, is it correct that the desired access restrictions still apply? In other words, VPN cannot be used to circumvent these kind of restrictions? Although the answer seems almost self-evident from the question itself, I am not sure what is all possible with port-forwarding, MAC-address spoofing etc...

UPDATE: To prevent third parties from using the MAC address to track devices, Android, Linux, iOS, and Windows[5] have implemented MAC address randomization. In June 2014, Apple announced that future versions of their iOS platform would randomize MAC addresses for all WiFi connections. The Linux kernel has supported MAC address randomization during network scans since March 2015,[6] but drivers need to be updated to use this feature.[7] Windows has supported it since the release of Windows 10[5] in July 2015 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing#MAC_Address_Randomization_in_WiFi

So, based on the answers below, so far, the VPN would usually not be able to spoof the MAC address, but LAN access control based on MAC address is made difficult or impossible by the intentional address randomization within the device.

Comment: Well, I am perplexed by this. The VPN on my phone goes straight through the access restriction imposed by the DSL WiFI router. With the VPN off, access is blocked. The modem is an Actiontec T3200.

Answer (score 2):

A VPN is nothing else than another TCP IP connection. So the best approach would always be to block the dst address of the VPN. However, since this is normally not easy (there are tons of vpn dst ips). The connection, should be dropped if the source host MAC address is not allowed. In other words, you should treat the VPN as a Webpage. Just as you would block yahoo, you should block the vpn provider. Once the vpn is established, the mac would be allowed to do whatever it wish .

Comment: Blocking VPNs is also a option to ensure it cannot be used to spoof the MAC address (if spoofing by a VPN is at all possible), but from my readings it seems quite difficult to do since there's an "arms race" between detecting VPNs  and avoiding detection. Detecting a VPN involves detecting IP traffic to predominantly one IP address or maintaining a black-list of known IP addresses.

Comment: That is correct. Another approach would be to block all VPN traffic ports. This will work, but then no one on the network would be able to access any VPN. (This is sometimes not desirable.

Comment: Indeed, that would work with tame and thus compliant VPNs, but a rogue VPN can use any port, incl 443 and 80. It's a stubborn problem. I am thinking of registering permissible MAC addresses, and then restricting them as required. It does require manual work, but for a small network with few newcomers it might be manageable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there are no VPNs that do this. Theoretically spoofing a MAC address could work, but it isn't what a VPN is designed to do. Even then there aren't really any simple options for spoofing MAC addresses on Windows.

So the desired access restrictions will still apply.

Comment: I updated my question. As I am reading up on it, it seems that recent devices randomize their MAC address. The tracking it intends to prevent is de-facto also a go-around.

Answer (score 1):

As per [OSI-Layer Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), the VPN Connection is just an Application with (hopefully) encrypted communication (OpenVPN, SSL/TLS-VPN, IPSec) on Layer 4 (e.g. TCP/UDP) the packages themself are handled by the PHY (e.g. Network card, WiFi Modul, etc.). Therefore your MAC filter will detect these packages as packages from this MAC even if it can't read the content. The only bypasses for the MAC filter are MAC spoofing or using another PC on the network as a proxy or NAT device than your Router with the MAC filter will see this PC as the sending device.